# FragmentStatePagerAdapter returning same fragment in current page and cached page

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to load fragment with viewpager with tab layout. I am passing different id's to load same fragment with different data in `getItem()` but it is always returning fragment with same data on first time and when I swipe through next screens and came back to first screen then it will showing correct data.
Any solution or info is very helpful.

I am calling adapter like this in my `onCreate()` and it always return same data for position 0 and 1.

```
    MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter (getSupportFragmentManager(),bundle); 
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

**My Adapter**

```
    static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private  Bundle b;

    public MyPagerAdapter (FragmentManager fm,Bundle b) {
        super(fm);
        this.b=b;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        ContentListFragment fragment = new ContentListFragment();

        b.putString("id", tabList.get(position).get("id"));
        fragment.setArguments(b);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return  tabList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabList.get(position).get("title");
    }

}
```

**Edit**

**ContentListFragment.java**

```
public class ContentListFragment extends Fragment{

private static final String TAG="ContentListFragment";  
private String id,type;
private TextView norecord;
private View rootView;

private List<AppReading> appReadingList;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ContentRecyclerAdapter adapter;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_list, container,false);

    initView();
    initData();

    return rootView;
}


private void initView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    norecord=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.norecord);
    recyclerView=(RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
}

private void initData() {       
    id=getArguments().getString("id");      
    getContentList(category);
}


// Get records by category
private void getContentList(String id){
    Log.d(TAG, "getContentList: "+id);
    Dao dao=new Dao(getActivity());
    dao.open();
    appReadingList=dao.getContentList(id);
    dao.close();

    //Set adapter if data available
    if(appReadingList.size()>0){
        adapter=new ContentRecyclerAdapter();

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(),R.drawable.divider));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new FadeInLeftAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new SlideInLeftAnimationAdapter(adapter));
    }else{
        norecord.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}


private class ContentRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContentRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);
        return  holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,final int position) {

        holder.itemContent.setText(appReadingList.get(position).getTitle());
        holder.itemDate.setText(appReadingList.get(position).getAddDate());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return appReadingList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }


    class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView itemContent, itemDate ;
        RelativeLayout listItem;

        ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            itemContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemcontent);
            itemDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemdate);
            listItem=(RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rlListItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the ContentListFragment correctly receives the Bundle and correctly gets the data with in? Make a Log in ContentListFragment to  check it.

Comment: I have checked log It passed different ids in getitem but when returning it always return both fragment for position id 1. I dont know why It is not returning fragment for position 0.

Comment: Make a log not in getItem() but in ContentListFragment's onCreateView()

Comment: I am not getting position 0 id in my ContentListFragmentent. For both position I am getting position 1 id.

Comment: I'm not sure but the follow up reader would find it easier to post an answer if you could post your ContentListFragment and the complete adapter. I noticed that the getItem()  in your adaper does not call b=new Bundle() or the implementation of the tabList list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112573/discussion-between-malith-lakshan-and-ved).